# ReporteRs rotated text in cells

Tags: r, reporters

Building on [Flextable examples](https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/articles/flextable_examples.html) I would like to rotate the text in the cells of the first column ("Alive","Melanoma","Non-melanoma"):

```
data = structure(list(Status = c("Alive", "Alive", "Alive", "Alive",
"Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Melanoma", "Non-melanoma",
"Non-melanoma", "Non-melanoma", "Non-melanoma"), Gender = c("Female",
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male",
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"), Ulceration = c("Absent",
"Present", "Absent", "Present", "Absent", "Present", "Absent",
"Present", "Absent", "Present", "Absent", "Present"), n = c(68L,
23L, 24L, 19L, 8L, 20L, 8L, 21L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L), Mean = c(1.693,
2.972, 1.468, 4.319, 2.139, 4.724, 3.266, 5.143, 1.667, 3.302,
2.42, 8.053), SD = c(2.004, 2.593, 1.719, 2.423, 1.184, 4.128,
4.681, 2.862, 1.141, 3.713, 2.499, 4.019)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Status",
"Gender", "Ulceration", "n", "Mean", "SD"), row.names = c(NA,
-12L))

MyFTable = FlexTable( data = data[ , c( "Status", "Gender", "Ulceration", "n", "Mean") ],
                      header.columns = FALSE )

MyFTable = spanFlexTableRows( MyFTable, j = "Status", runs = as.character( data$Status ) )
MyFTable = spanFlexTableRows( MyFTable, j = "Gender", runs = as.character( data$Gender ) )
MyFTable
```

From the documentation I thought that the text.direction property should take care of this:

```
baseCellProp = cellProperties()
MyFTable[,1]=chprop( baseCellProp, text.direction="btlr")
MyFTable
```

Is there another way? (or is there a way to make this one work?)

Comment: It only works in headers and for Word and PowerPoint outputs. Use flextable package instead to get what you want. https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/

Comment: When should one use flextable+officer and when Reporters (with FlexTable) to create Word documents with tables?

Comment: Goal of flextable+officer is to replace ReporteRs as java dependency is a pain in term of maintenance. So if you're starting, it's better to not use ReporteRs and use officer instead.

Comment: Is there a direct way in flextable to use fonts? Likewise, I would like to draw a thicker border on the rows below merged cells. Is there a way out-of-the box to either get the indices of the merged cells or to add such a border? (I posted it also as a separate question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700492/r-flextable-how-to-add-a-table-wide-horizontal-border-under-a-merged-cell