# R flextable - How to add a table-wide horizontal border under a merged cell

Tags: r, flextable

Is there a smart way to have a horizontal border table wide when you have merged cells? (In the example below, it is not yet table wide).

Or should I write a function to calculate the correct index?

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

myft <- flextable(head(mtcars), 
                  col_keys = c("am", "carb", "gear", "mpg", "drat" ))%>% 
  theme_vanilla()%>%
  merge_v(j = c("am"))%>%border(border.bottom = fp_border(style = "solid", width=2), i=c(3,6), part="body")

myft
```

Comment: Are you talking about that issue? https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/6

Comment: Not really. More about whether there is an out of the box way to replace i=c(3,6) in a more generic way. Alternatively, I have to write a function to determine for each category in the merged cells column the number of observations in each category and construct a vector with indices. It would be nice to be able to use merge_v in a way to determine the location of the border.

Comment: nice suggestion. I will provide a function for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much simpler solution is to add a column that indicates which rows need a bottom border and then add an `hline()` with a row selection that uses that value. That helper selection can be kept out of the table by only selecting the columns you want to show in the original flextable specification using `col_keys`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

your_flextable = tibble(
  col_group = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
  the_value = rnorm(length(col_group))
) %>%
  group_by(col_group) %>%
  mutate(
    is_last_val_in_group = row_number() == max(row_number())
  ) %>%
  flextable(col_keys = c('col_group', 'the_value')) %>%
  merge_v(j = 'col_group') %>%
  hline(i = ~is_last_val_in_group == TRUE, border = fp_border()) %>%
  fix_border_issues()
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code for what you want. It needs more work to be generic - the example is only adapted when column 1 is the only that has merged cells.

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

bigborder <- fp_border(style = "solid", width=2)
myft <- flextable(head(mtcars), 
                  col_keys = c("am", "carb", "gear", "mpg", "drat" ))%>% 
  theme_vanilla()%>%
  merge_v(j = c("am")) 

# here starts the trick
row_loc <- rle(cumsum( myft$body$spans$columns[,1] ))$values
myft <- myft %>% 
  border(border.bottom = bigborder, i=row_loc, j = 2:5, part="body") 
myft <- myft %>% 
  border(border.bottom = bigborder, 
         i = myft$body$spans$columns[,1] > 1, j = 1, part="body") %>% 


  border(border.bottom = bigborder, border.top = bigborder, part = "header")
myft
```

Comment: nice use of rle