# Table-wide horizontal border under merged cells do not show up in docx (but display fine on other format)

Tags: r, flextable

**Context:** using the tricks described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710723/10264278) I was able to get horizontal line under merged cells.

**Problem:** when I use `save_as_docx()`, the bottom lines of the 1st column (the one with merged cells) do not show up. In addition, format of the bottom line of the last row it not correct.
However, if I use any of .pptx, .html or .png outputs, it works fine.

**Question:** is it possible to make .docx output have full width bottom lines with correct format even under merged cells?

**Reprex:**

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

bigborder <- fp_border(style = "solid", width=2)

fl <- iris %>% 
  # make iris a smaller dataset for display purpose
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 5) %>% 
  # just to have species as the 1st column
  select(Species, everything()) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  merge_v(j = ~ Species) %>% 
  # bottom border of column 2:ncol(iris)
  border(border.bottom = bigborder, i = rle(cumsum(.$body$spans$columns[,1] ))$values, j = 2:ncol(iris), part="body") %>% 
  # bottom border of 1st colum
  border(border.bottom = bigborder, i = .$body$spans$columns[,1] > 1, j = 1, part="body")

fl

# Bottom lines of 1st column do not display with docx output
save_as_docx(fl, path = "./fl.docx")

# Bottom lines of 1st column display right with these format
save_as_html(fl, path = "./fl.html")
save_as_pptx(fl, path = "./fl.pptx")
save_as_image(fl, path = "./fl.png")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**.docx output:**

[image: Word .docx output]

**.pptx, .html, .png output (expected one):**

[image: correct output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got the expected output using `hline()` and `fix_border_issues()` as recommended [here](https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/6#issuecomment-370485610)

```
fl <- iris %>% 
  # make iris a smaller dataset for display purpose
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 5) %>% 
  # just to have species as the 1st column
  select(Species, everything()) %>% 
  # Flextable
  flextable() %>% 
  merge_v(j = ~ Species) %>% 
  hline(i = rle(cumsum(.$body$spans$columns[,1] ))$values, border = bigborder) %>% 
  fix_border_issues()
fl
```

**.docx output:**

[image]